# Использование Interstitial Ad в firemonkey

Tags: admob, firemonkey

Здравствуйте!

Решил воспользоваться межстраничной рекламой AdMob по рецепту из [этой статьи](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2015/04/how-to-use-admob-interstitial-ads-with.html)

**Вопрос:** не могу понять, как отключить Test Mode?

Answer (score 0):

А разгадка одна...

В примере от Daniel Spinetti была такая строчка:

```
LADRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(MainActivity.getDeviceID);
```

Метод addTestDevice отвечает за включение Test Mode. Если просто убрать данную строку, баннер будет работать как надо.

А вот и ссылка на документацию(английский), где описаны все методы для работы с межстраничными баннерами:[ссылка](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder#addTestDevice(java.lang.String)). В RAD Studio все из этих методов имеются.

Answer (score 0):

```
IAdvertisment.TestMode:=false;
```